# LINQ: Selecting duplicate rows according to Column-Value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, syntax

I'm trying to display those rows in my DataGrid, which share the same column-value.

For example, for Persons, who have the same Surname, I tried this:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = _dataContext.Addresses.GroupBy(a => a.SurName).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1).Select(grp => grp.Key);
```

This works seemingly, as my WPF DataGrid contains rows after this command... Eventually it only displays empty rows, as no column is filled with a value.

Or I tried this with Persons, who have the same City:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = _dataContext.Addresses.GroupBy(a => a.City).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1).Select(grp => grp.Key).Select(a => a);
```

Is there any proper way to do this?

Comment: I'm unsure of the question being asked. To clarify, the first code sample works, but the second sample doesn't?

Comment: Both do not work, as the first one returns only empty rows (but it does return some, at least...), and the second one returns nothing

Comment: So that means you have multiple rows with blank values for SurName in your database? Seems like they're both working, just not returning the data you expect. It would help to see class definitions for `Address` and `Person`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are only selecting the key in your example:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = _dataContext.Addresses.GroupBy(a => a.SurName).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1).Select(grp => **grp.Key**);
```

What I assume you are trying to do is to select the whole row:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = _dataContext.Addresses.GroupBy(a => a.SurName).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1).SelectMany(grp => grp.Select(r=>r));
```

To compare first and last names:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = _dataContext.Addresses.GroupBy(a => new Tuple<String, String>(a.ForeName, a.SurName)).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1).SelectMany(grp => grp.Select(r=>r));
```

EDIT: For L2E, you can (I think) use anonymous types:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = _dataContext.Addresses.GroupBy(a => new { a.ForeName, a.SurName }).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1).SelectMany(grp => grp.Select(r=>r));
```

The above could be incorrect- not 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this works... How should I modify the query in order to not only compare the SurNames, but the ForeNames also? .GroupBy(a => a.ForeName, a.SurName) does not work.

Comment: You mean "show rows that match on first name and last name"?  See my edit.

Comment: Yes, the rows where the FirstName and LastName are equal

Comment: This code raises the exception: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.